# Need to append flight name to a dataframe after every action button click in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Need to insert a new flight name to a dataframe after every action button click.

I have tried to use eventreactive for the first click and used rbind outside of eventreactive which did not work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Calculator"),
  fluidRow(
    mainPanel(
      h4('Results'),
      tags$hr(),
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Flight",            
                   textInput("flightname","Enter the flight Name",""),
                   selectInput("addedvalue", "Added Value:",
                               c("No","Yes")),
                   tags$hr(),
                   actionButton("go_fli", "Go")),
          tabPanel("Tactic", 
                   textInput("tacticname","Enter the tactic Name",""),
                   tags$hr(),
                   actionButton("go_tac", "Go"))
        ),
      DT::dataTableOutput("Test_Table")
    )
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {
  Testdata <- data.frame("FlightName" = character(), "AddedValue" = character())

  fli <-eventReactive(input$go_fli,{
    fli <- data.frame("FlightName"=input$flightname, "AddedValue"=input$addedvalue)
  })

  Testdata <- reactive({rbind(fli(),Testdata())})

  output$Test_Table = renderDataTable(Testdata())

}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

For the first time, flight name = Delta -> click go button
For the second time, flight name = American Airlines -> click go button
And the added value is No for first and Yes for the second time

The dataframe should be displayed like below.

Delta               No
American Airlines   Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reactiveValues` in conjunction with `observeEvent`.

Reactive values can be modified within observers, so you can bind rows to your `data.frame` every time the button is pressed.

#### Code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Initialize reactive values
  rv <- reactiveValues(fli = data.frame("FlightName" = character(), "AddedValue" = character()))

  observeEvent(input$go_fli, {
    # Bind new row to rv$fli
    rv$fli <- rbind(
      rv$fli, 
      data.frame("FlightName"=input$flightname, "AddedValue"=input$addedvalue)
    )
  })

  output$Test_Table <- renderDataTable(rv$fli)

}
```